# Excel multiple grouping on table for different pivot tables?

Tags: excel, windows-7, excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007 and using several pivot charts which reference the same table of data. I change the data daily, copy and pasting the data from another source. Is it possible to change the grouping on the table so that I can view the data differently in different pivot tables? For example, one graph views the data by hour and another by month and another by day. It seems that when I change the grouping for one graph, it changes it on every one. My solution has been to copy and paste in the data into three separate tables for data with each one having different groupings.

Comment: Your grouping problem is due to the fact that you're using the same PivotData for all your charts. When you build the chart using the wizard, Excel ask you a question about this.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible solution is to split dates in different columns and calculate all the aggregation levels needed using

```
 - =YEAR([date]), =MONTH([date]), =DAY([date]), =HOUR([date]), =MINUTE([date])
 - =CEILING(MONTH([date])/3;1) for quarter
```

and pull these fields in & out of your Pivot tables / charts.

Comment: So you are saying to created multiple columns to represent the date column in different views so that I can group the new columns by different groupings? Hmmmmm, I can give it a try. Do you know what I mean though, Excel will re-group the table everytime you want to group it differently for a different Pivot graph and really only allows one grouping per table...or is it one grouping per column?